# How to view a particular unicode character?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am currently using Quantal and I am trying to write in Oriya, a South Asian language. The problem is even though changing the keyboard layout to Oriya works in most cases, I am unable to type the Unicode character 0B5F (Oriya Character YYA).

In Fedora, it used to work by using the combo **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>**.

I've changed one of the lines in the section **xkb_symbols "ori"** in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in from

```
key <AB10> { [  U0b2f, U0040    ] };
```

to

```
key <AB10> { [  U0b2f, U0b54    ] };
```

But when I type in gedit, I get a strange box-like character filled with 0B5F.

How do I fix the keyboard mapping so that I can print the Unicode 0B5F on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange box like character filled with 0B5F indicates that the character being referenced is indeed U+0b5f, but the font doesn't support it.

Try changing the font you're using in gedit to a font that does support Oriya symbols

```
Menu > Edit > Preferences > TAB(Font & Color) > Editor Font
```

Comment: Changing to Lohit Oriya font did not help.

Comment: does your square box contain 0b54 or 0b5f? I've managed to get gedit to show the ୟ (U+0b5f) symbol, but the (U+0b54) seems not to map to a symbol in Oriya symbols (and you've mentioned U=0b54 in your question above)

Comment: should the entry in X11/xkb/symbols/in say "key <AB10> { [  U0b2f, U0b5f    ] };" instead of "key <AB10> { [  U0b2f, U0b54    ] };"

Comment: Man... what a newb mistake!! Of course it was U0b5f. Now I feel silly asking this question!! Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Yup, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

### General answer on "how to type a Unicode Character?"

Example, to get this symbol `⌀` 
Do:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> you will get `̲u`
2. now you can release your fingers out of the keyboard
   and continue by typing your Unicode `2300` , now you have: `̲u̲2̲3̲0̲0`
3. press your <kbd>spaceBar</kbd> and you get `⌀`

To know the list of Unicode characters, consult [this list](http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html).

---

So for your code `0b5f`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and `0b5f` gives `ୟ`